# preparing data for haar training OpenCV

Tags: linux, opencv, cmd

i want to make my own haar classifier for detection of hand, so i was following the toutorial given at 
[Naotoshi Seo](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html). In this tutorial various linux command are used and i don't have linux.
some command are: 
`$ find [image dir] -name '*.[image ext]' > [description file]`
`$ createsamples -info samples.dat -vec samples.vec -w 20 -h 20`

so how can i use these command on my windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "find" command creates a text file with the names of your image files. You can do that by hand if you want.

The second one is not a standard Linux command, but, I assume, one of the tools you need to create the classifier. If you want to use Windows you will have to download the Windows version of the tools in that tutorial. He uses Cygwin so you will need to install that as well.

Another option is to download the Ubuntu Live distribution and install it on a USB memory stick. You can then boot from the USB stick, create your classifier in Linux, then go beck to Widows when you're done.

Comment: Do you know any tutorial about haar training? please pvrovide me link if you know. Thanks for providing above info.